# If $\{f(b + x) - f(a - x)\}/(b - a + 2x) = f'(c)$ then show that $c$ is an increasing function of $x$

Tags: calculus

> Let $f$ be twice differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and also assume that $f, f', f''$ are increasing. Let $a\leq b$ and $x > 0$. By mean value theorem there is a $c \in (a - x, b + x)$ such that $$\frac{f(b + x) - f(a - x)}{b - a + 2x} = f'(c)$$ and clearly $c$ depends on $x$. Show that $c$ is an increasing function of $x$.

I am assuming that by "increasing" we mean the strict version otherwise taking a constant $f$ makes the definition of $c$ ambiguous.

The question looks bit clumsy because the dependence of $c$ on $x$ is not direct in terms of a formula. However since $f'$ in increasing it is sufficient to show that $f'(c)$ is increasing. I tried to differentiate the equation defining $f'(c)$ to obtain $$\frac{(b - a + 2x)\{f'(b + x) + f'(a - x)\} - 2\{f(b + x) - f(a - x)\}}{(b - a + 2x)^{2}} = \frac{(b - a + 2x)\{f'(b + x) + f'(a - x) - 2f'(c)\}}{(b - a + 2x)^{2}}$$ But I am not able to show that $f'(b + x) + f'(a - x) > 2f'(c)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality $a=b$, because we can set $a'=b'=\frac{a+b}2$ and get the full result for $x>\frac{b-a}2$. Then
$$\frac{f(a+x)-f(a-x)}{2x}=f'(c)=f'(a+(c-a))$$
So by setting $f'(x)=f(a+x)$ we can suppose that $a=b=0$ as this doesn't affect any assumptions or what want to prove.

Then as you noted we want to prove
$$f'(x)+f'(-x)>2f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}x$$
which follows from
$$x(f'(x)+f'(-x))-(f(x)-f(-x))>0$$
This is equal to $0$ when $x=0$, if we check the derivative
$$f'(x)+f'(-x)+x(f''(x)-f''(-x))-(f'(x)+f'(-x))>0\Longleftrightarrow x(f''(x)-f''(-x))>0$$
we see it holds for all $x>0$, because the second derivative is increasing.

Comment: Your simplification to $a = b = 0$ is really very smart. After that the problem is not that difficult as you have shown in your answer. Really nice. +1.